# EntityFramework Include extended

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, reflection, entity-framework-6

I have a method that generate Entityframework include automatically from an object.
the string look like this

```
"x=> x.Connectors , x=> x.BlockEntryFieldsGroup.Select(GhIm=> GhIm.BlockEntry_Field.Select(GhImcc=> GhImcc.BlockEntry_Value)) , x=> x.BlockEntryOffSet"
```

and i would like to convert the given string to `params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes`
right now i use `CSharpCodeProvider` to dynamically convert it.

Is there any better way to do this without using `CSharpCodeProvider`?

Comment: Perhaps https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/?

Comment: need an example